# Is there anyway to reset the identity of a Table Variable?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table variable:

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeData NVARCHAR(300))
```

After I have inserted 250 rows, I need to "Start Over" with the table.  I do this:

```
DELETE FROM @MyTableVar
```

Is there anything I can do to the table variable so that this:

```
insert into @MyTableVar Values("TestData")
select * from @MyTableVar
```

will return this:

```
_______________________________
|    ID     |    SomeData     |
|___________|_________________|
|           |                 |   
|     1     |    TestData     |        
|___________|_________________|
```

instead of this:

```
_______________________________
|    ID     |    SomeData     |
|___________|_________________|
|           |                 |   
|    251    |    TestData     |        
|___________|_________________|
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147210/how-can-i-reseed-an-identity-column-in-a-t-sql-table-variable

Answer (score 17):

Instead relying on an Identity, why not use the new ranking functions such as Row_Number

```
Insert @MyTableVar( Id, Value )
Select Row_Number() Over ( Order By Value )
    , Value
From SomeOtherTable
```

Comment: This is close to working, but it re-orders my result set (or at least in my example it does).  The order that I insert thing is very very important in this case.

Comment: @Vaccano - The order that I showed was for example purposes only. You can obviously change it whatever you wish. The point was to illustrate the approach rather than a specific solution. We're never told in your question what order you were using.

Comment: @Vaccano - One more item, if the order is important, then presumably you are applying an Order By when you insert into your table var with an identity. That same order would be used in the ranking function.

Comment: Alas, I am getting my data from an XML variable (Using XQuery) so I don't have any order by or strong Id to use.  It just comes out in the order it is in the file (and the order I need it in).

Comment: @Vaccano - First, if that's the case, then that's a critical piece to your problem. You should add that to the question. There may still be a way to dictate an order. Second, I'm not sure I would rely on the fact that the order as entered into the table exactly matched the physical order in the Xml snippet without explicitly stating as such. I doubt that's a supported "feature" on which you can depend and which will not change under any condition or in future versions.

Comment: I had a similar situation, but the example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147210/how-can-i-reseed-an-identity-column-in-a-t-sql-table-variable showed how I could use my identity column to retain the ordering of the data, and still "reset" my numbers back to 1 each time by using "row_number() OVER (ORDER BY <my_identity_column>)"

Answer (score 6):

Instead of re-seeding the IDENTITY, why not just delete from the @table variable, then use ROW_NUMBER() against the input? e.g. instead of the lazy

```
SELECT * FROM @MyTableVar;
```

...use...

```
SELECT ID = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID), SomeData FROM @MyTableVar;
```

Now you don't need to care what the seed is, whether it starts at 1, whether there are any gaps, etc.

Comment: Just to clarify, this seems similar but is different from the suggestion from Thomas, as he suggested trying to insert the data with a ROW_NUMBER() applied first. If there are multiple insert statements happening independently, applying a ROW_NUMBER() first won't work, especially because there may not be an obvious order within the INSERT statement itself.

Comment: If there are multiple inserts happening, the identity approach would also break would it not? You might get gaps or an order that is unexpected (e.g. 1st insert A,B,C which get identity values of 1,2,3. 2nd insert A,B,D which get 4,5,6 but not the same as the sequence). It really comes down to when the OP needs the sequence and I get the impression they need a sequence multiple times thus the question about how to reseed the identity.

Comment: @Thomas, if the op has ensured that the IDENTITY values that get assigned occur in the correct order (I assume he is inserting rows one by one, and that the "order" is dictated by something that is not already in the table) then this approach should work fine. The only problem the op was having is that the values he was getting on subsequent queries from the table were not starting at 1. If he keeps the IDENTITY column he can still pull the data ordered by insert but use ROW_NUMBER() to generate a 1,2,3 sequence regardless of lowest value, gaps, etc.

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately there is no function to reseed identity column in table variable, I know this question is very old, but in case other people encountered the same problem, I would like to share my method to solve this problem.

```
/* declare another table variable with same structure and perform select insert*/

DECLARE @MyTableVar1 TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeData NVARCHAR(300))
insert into @MyTableVar1
select someData from @MyTableVar
```

However, If you want to perform dynamic reseeding inside a loop, I would suggest using a table object

Answer (score 2):

You can't reseed the identity value on a Table Variable but you can do the same thing with a Temp Table:

```
CREATE  TABLE #TAB(ID INT IDENTITY,VALUE VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @RESEED INT = 32
DBCC CHECKIDENT(#TAB,RESEED,@RESEED)
INSERT INTO #TAB  
SELECT 'TEST'
SELECT * FROM #TAB
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are re-using your table, if I got it right, how about you do not initialize your counters to 1 and instead use this as an example?

```
DECLARE @ctr INT
IF @ctr IS NULL or @ctr <= 0 --this part is to control @ctr value on loops
   SET @ctr = 1
ELSE
   SELECT @ctr = MIN(id) FROM @tbl
```

This way, you are not restarting your loop to 1 nor is there a need for you to truncate the table.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to have another int column on your table variable and update that column with modulo after the insert is finished?

```
declare @Mytablevar table
(
id int identity(1,1)
,id1 int
somedata nvarchar(300)
)

-- insert your data as you would.  After insert is finished, do the following:

update @mytablevar set id1 = case when id > 250 then id % 250 else id end
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on net but i am not able to get any solution on reset identity for table variable.

If you are able to use temp table  #MyTableVar instead of table  @MyTableVar variable then it is possible to reset identity value

```
   DBCC CHECKIDENT('TableName', RESEED, NewValue)

   DBCC CHECKIDENT(#MyTableVar, RESEED, 0)
```

Newvalue must be one less than the newIdentiyValue

```
   NewValue= NewIdentity-1;
```

If you still want to learn more you can refer my blog
http://tryconcepts.blogspot.in/2012/08/reset-identity-column-to-new-id.html

Answer (score 0):

I just had this idea and it works!!! :

```
declare @TableVariable table (
    IdentityColumn int identity(1,1),
    SomeOtherValue int,
    DesiredResult int
)
declare @FirstIdentityValueEachTimeYouLoadDataToTable int
declare @Count int
set @Count = 1

while @Count <= 5
begin
    delete @TableVariable

    insert into @TableVariable (SomeOtherValue) select 45
    insert into @TableVariable (SomeOtherValue) select 90
    insert into @TableVariable (SomeOtherValue) select 2

    select @FirstIdentityValueEachTimeYouLoadDataToTable = min(IdentityColumn) from @TableVariable

    Update @TableVariable set DesiredResult = IdentityColumn - @FirstIdentityValueEachTimeYouLoadDataToTable + 1

    select * from @TableVariable
    set @Count = @Count + 1
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you use temporary table?
This is a sample how to do this with a temp table.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTableVar (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), SomeData NVARCHAR(300))

insert #MyTableVar(SomeData) values ('test1'), ('test2')

---doesn't work
DELETE FROM #MyTableVar 

insert #MyTableVar(SomeData) values ('test3'), ('test4')
select * from #MyTableVar 

--resets the identity
truncate table #MyTableVar
insert #MyTableVar(SomeData) values ('test3'), ('test4')
select * from #MyTableVar
```

Regards

Piotr

Answer (score -1):

DELETE FROM does not reset identity.
TRUNCATE does.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using SQL Server then use this `DBCC CHECKIDENT('Customer', RESEED, 0)` Where Customer is a table name. When you insert records into table after this command your primery key column value will be start from 1 again.

Read this 
http://codedotnets.blogspot.in/2012/09/how-to-reset-identity-in-sql-server.html