# XQuery and Node Ids

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I have this variable:

```
declare @xmlDoc XML
```

it has the following xml stored in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table1>
    <Sharedparam>shared</Sharedparam>
    <Antoher>sahre</Antoher>
    <RandomParam2>Good stuff</RandomParam2>
    <MoreParam>and more</MoreParam>
    <ResultsParam>2</ResultsParam>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>       
    <RandomParam2>do you</RandomParam2>
    <MoreParam>think</MoreParam>
    <ResultsParam>2</ResultsParam>
  </Table1>
  <Table1>
    <Sharedparam>Last</Sharedparam>
    <Antoher> Set </Antoher>
    <RandomParam2> of </RandomParam2>
    <MoreParam>values</MoreParam>
    <ResultsParam>are here</ResultsParam>
  </Table1>
  <Table1 />
</NewDataSet>
```

I have this query that I am using to get the data:

```
declare @xmlDoc XML
set @xmlDoc = '' -- Stack Overflow could not handle the xml all on one line.

SELECT   -- Param 1
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[1])', 'varchar(50)') as Param1Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Param1Value,             
         -- Param2
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[2])', 'varchar(50)') as Param2Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as Param2Value, 

         -- Param3           
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[3])', 'varchar(50)') as Param3Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[3]', 'varchar(100)') as Param3Value,

         -- Param 4
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[4])', 'varchar(50)') as Param4Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[4]', 'varchar(100)') as Param4Value,

         -- Param 5
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[5])', 'varchar(50)') as Param5Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[5]', 'varchar(100)') as Param5Value

 FROM    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1') AS TBL(SParam)
```

I need a way to add to my results the order that they came from the xml file.  (Which was the first instance of Table1, then the second....).

For reasons of [SQL table variable limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471210/is-there-anyway-to-reset-the-identity-of-a-table-variable), I can't use an identity column to keep this straight.  (For other reasons, I don't want to use a temporary table.)

I am hoping that there is a cool SQL XML function that will return some kind of internally assigned Node ID. (Or some other similar manner of ordering.)

Note, I do not control this XML Structure (I am a reader only) so I cannot make changes to add in an ID attribute.

Any advice would be great!

**EDIT/Update:**

I would really like to have this data like this:

```
1  |    SharedParam   |   shared
1  |    Antoher       |   sahre
1  |    RandomParam2  |   Good stuff
1  |    MoreParam     |   and more
1  |    ResultsParam  |   and more
2  |    RandomParam2  |   do you
2  |    MoreParam     |   think
2  |    ResultsParam  |   2
3  |    Sharedparam   |   Last
3  |    Antoher       |   Set 
.
.
.
```

But I am coming up short.  I can get it into columns (more or less), but I don't know how to do the numbering.  If you have any ideas I would love to hear them.

**EDIT:**
I figured out the query to do this (with some help from the internet).  It looks like this:

```
SELECT  TBL.SParam.value('local-name(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') as ParamName,
        TBL.SParam.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') ParamValue, 
        TBL.SParam.value('for $s in . return count(../*[. << $s]) + 1', 'int') ParamPosition,
        TBL.SParam.value('for $s in . return count(../../*[. << $s]) - 1', 'int') ParamIteration 
FROM    @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1/*') AS TBL(SParam)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a number table and [position()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191225.aspx)

```
 SELECT  N.Number as ID,
         -- Param 1
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[1])', 'varchar(50)') as Param1Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Param1Value,             
         -- Param2
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[2])', 'varchar(50)') as Param2Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as Param2Value, 

         -- Param3           
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[3])', 'varchar(50)') as Param3Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[3]', 'varchar(100)') as Param3Value,

         -- Param 4
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[4])', 'varchar(50)') as Param4Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[4]', 'varchar(100)') as Param4Value,

         -- Param 5
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[5])', 'varchar(50)') as Param5Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[5]', 'varchar(100)') as Param5Value

 FROM master..spt_values as N
    cross apply @xmldoc.nodes('/NewDataSet/Table1[position()=sql:column("N.Number")]') AS TBL(SParam)
 where N.type = 'P' and
       N.number between 1 and @xmlDoc.value('count(/NewDataSet/Table1)', 'int')
```

Comment: why the `and N.number between 1 and @xmlDoc.value('count(/NewDataSet/Table1)', 'int')`

Comment: @Conrad The cross apply will happen for every row in the number table so when using master..spt_values there will be a query against XML 2048 times. So I thought it would be good to first limit the number table to what is actually needed.

Comment: @Conrad Some quick tests shows that (on my rather sad laptop) this particular query takes 195 ms without the `between` and 4 ms with.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I realized that I need my results a bit differently (I updated my question).  If you feel up to taking a look I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this connect request to [Fully support position() in xquery](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/383888/fully-support-position-in-xquery) The requestor offers a couple of work arounds that might be usful to you

Based on the second workaround I wrote the following

```
SELECT  
         p.number,

         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[1])', 'varchar(50)') as Param1Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as Param1Value,             
         -- Param2
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[2])', 'varchar(50)') as Param2Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[2]', 'varchar(100)') as Param2Value, 

         -- Param3           
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[3])', 'varchar(50)') as Param3Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[3]', 'varchar(100)') as Param3Value,

         -- Param 4
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[4])', 'varchar(50)') as Param4Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[4]', 'varchar(100)') as Param4Value,

         -- Param 5
         TBL.SParam.value('local-name((*)[5])', 'varchar(50)') as Param5Name,
         TBL.SParam.value('(*)[5]', 'varchar(100)') as Param5Value
 FROM    
    master..spt_values p CROSS APPLY 


     @xmldoc.nodes('NewDataSet/Table1[position()=sql:column("p.number")]') AS TBL(SParam)  
 WHERE P.type = 'P'
```

Which returns the following

```
number      Param1Name                                         Param1Value                                                                                          Param2Name                                         Param2Value                                                                                          Param3Name                                         Param3Value                                                                                          Param4Name                                         Param4Value                                                                                          Param5Name                                         Param5Value
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Sharedparam                                        shared                                                                                               Antoher                                            sahre                                                                                                RandomParam2                                       Good stuff                                                                                           MoreParam                                          and more                                                                                             ResultsParam                                       2
2           RandomParam2                                       do you                                                                                               MoreParam                                          think                                                                                                ResultsParam                                       2                                                                                                                                                       NULL                                                                                                                                                    NULL
3           Sharedparam                                        Last                                                                                                 Antoher                                             Set                                                                                                 RandomParam2                                        of                                                                                                  MoreParam                                          values                                                                                               ResultsParam                                       are here
4                                                              NULL                                                                                                                                                    NULL                                                                                                                                                    NULL                                                                                                                                                    NULL                                                                                                                                                    NULL

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: +1 :) Add `where type ='P' ` and you can remove the distinct.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I realized that I need my results a bit differently (I updated my question).  If you feel up to taking a look I would appreciate it.