# sql xml order processor

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, xquery-sql

I was wondering if anyone could point me to a tutorial or give me suggestions on processing an XML "Request For Quote" document. Using SQL Server 2005. For example:

```
<MyQuote>  
<Header>  
  <Customer>XYZ</Customer>  
  <Material>Wood&</Material>  
<Header>  
<LineItems>  
<Line>  
   <Quantity>32</Quantity>  
   <Model>Chair 350</Model>  
   <Color>Red</Color>    
 </Line>  
  .   
</LineItems>  
</MyQuote>
```

Just getting my feet wet with XQuery. I need to shred this doc into individual Line Items, identify each one with a number, validate them calc a price. Also need to be able to add/edit/delete any one.  I can see how to get the lines into a table, but not how to ID them with a sequential number and apply a Stored Procedure to them. I need to randomly be able to process any request such as `validate line 6`,  `calc price for line 3` `delete line 4`, `change line 2 to Yellow`, etc.

I'm assuming the best way is to store the entire document as an XML column and transact against it as opposed to shredding and storing individual line items in a relational table?

Any advice, code, urls, etc would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if anyone could point me to a tutorial or give me
>   suggestions on processing an XML "Request For Quote" document. Using
>   SQL Server 2005

Here is some useful pages:

- [Introduction to XQuery in SQL Server 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- [XML Data Modification Language (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177454.aspx)
- [xml Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx)
- [XQuery Language Reference (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)

> I need to shred this doc into individual Line Items

This will give you all lines:

```
select 
  T.N.value('Quantity[1]', 'int') as Quantity,
  T.N.value('Model[1]', 'varchar(25)')    as Model,
  T.N.value('Color[1]', 'varchar(25)')    as Color
from @XML.nodes('/MyQuote/LineItems/Line') as T(N)
```

> each one with a number

Not so easy. Have a look at this answer. [XQuery and Node Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472533/xquery-and-node-ids/6473228#6473228)

> Also need to be able to add/edit/delete any one

Just use [modify() Method (xml Data Type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093.aspx)

```
I need to randomly be able to process any request such as validate line 6, calc price for line 3 delete line 4, change line 2 to Yellow
```

To get line 6 you should to this:

```
select 
  T.N.value('Quantity[1]', 'int') as Quantity,
  T.N.value('Model[1]', 'varchar(25)')    as Model,
  T.N.value('Color[1]', 'varchar(25)')    as Color
from @XML.nodes('/MyQuote/LineItems/Line[6]') as T(N)
```

`/MyQuote/LineItems/Line[6]` is the same as `/MyQuote/LineItems/Line[position()=6]`

> I'm assuming the best way is to store the entire document as an XML
>   column and transact against it as opposed to shredding and storing
>   individual line items in a relational table?

Don't know what is best for you but I would definitely shred the data to tables unless there where some really compelling reasons not to.