# How do I use an XQuery result list as a relational table in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a table with an XML column:

```
declare @xmltest xml;
set @xmltest =  
 '<list> 
    <el> <x>1</x> <y>one</y> </el>
    <el> <x>2</x> <y>two</y> </el>
  </list>'
```

Using XQuery, I can extract all the x's:

```
 select @xmltest.query('/list/el/x')
```

Which returns

```
<x>1</x><x>2</x>
```

But how do I extract them as a SQL table, with one x per row?

Even better, how do I extract them as an SQL table, with two columns, x and y so that I can then work on them with SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [nodes()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) and [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

```
select 
  N.value('x[1]', 'int') as x,
  N.value('y[1]', 'varchar(10)') as y
from @xmltest.nodes('/list/el') as T(N)
```

Result:

```
x           y
----------- ----------
1           one
2           two
```

Comment: Thanks again for the answer.  Can you recommend a good book or Web site for learning how to use XQuery in SQL Server effectively?  So far, I've found the MSDN materials extremely wordy, badly organized, and unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @Stavros - Have a look at this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749469/sql-xml-order-processor/6768891#6768891. It contains the links I use as reference. I do not know of any tutorial or book about XQuery in SQL Server.