# Regarding Clearing Auto Increment Value For Sql Table Variable 

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How can I reseed an identity column in a T-SQL table variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147210/how-can-i-reseed-an-identity-column-in-a-t-sql-table-variable)
>   [Is there anyway to reset the identity of a Table Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471210/is-there-anyway-to-reset-the-identity-of-a-table-variable)

Please go through the below sample and clarify my Question ?

```
Declare @temp table (sno int identity, myname varchar(30))
insert into @temp (myname) values ('Ravi')
insert into @temp (myname) values ('visu')
insert into @temp (myname) values ('pranesh')

delete from @temp

insert into @temp (myname) values ('Ravi')

select * from @temp
```

I am inserting 3 values in @temp table which has auto increment.  And later deleting the Value. Immediately adding another value. In this the Auto increment value id jumped to 4. I need to clear the auto increment value with out using dbcc statement.

Can anyone help me ? Your suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Please see this question from last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471210/is-there-anyway-to-reset-the-identity-of-a-table-variable/

Comment: If you need either of the following with an identity column, you're doing something wrong: requiring that it starts at a particular value; requiring no gaps between values. You should treat them as magical, opaque values, with no inherent meaning.

Comment: +1 Damien - it's a unique ID for the row, that's it

Answer (score 2):

[You cannot insert explicit values into an identity column for table variable](https://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2010/05/15/temporary-tables-vs-table-variables/)